# What is an offline method to force macbook webcam to capture at higher framerate than 12 fps?

Tags: video, macbook, webcam, camera, recording

I have a late 2013 MBP. The webcam captures at about 12 FPS by default, or if you shove extremely bright lights into the camera it might start capturing at a higher frame rate.

If I go to www.youtube.com/webcam, my webcam automatically starts capturing at about 60 fps. It doesn't make the video darker; it's not an exposure trade-off.

My problem is what if I want to record a video with my webcam but I don't have access to the internet or wwww.youtube.com/webcam. I tried downloading that web page but it doesn't run offline, it asks me to sign in to Google.

So does anyone know or have a script or whatever that page uses that forces my webcam to start capturing at a normal frame rate?

I have seen this question asked before and people will say things like different programs (Photo Booth, etc) have their own preferences. I am using the program OBS to record, but it will always 'capture' at 60FPS regardless of whether or not the actual video feed is 12FPS. You can specify the FPS rate you want to record at, from within OBS, but it doesn't actually change the frame rate the camera is capturing at, it only changes FPS rate of the video file being created. So it will just record a 12 FPS video and put it in a 60 FPS 'container' if you will.

Thank you so much for your help!

EDIT: I've tried out some different software, none of it seems to be able to communicate anything to the webcam itself. Other than whatever scripts are running on youtube.com/webcam. Surely it should not be so complicated to figure out what scripts are running on that website and then download them somehow, right? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm saying the bug is probably in OBS, not in your MacBook's built-in camera. So I'm asking if you're looking for some tool you can use to force OBS to do the right thing (or force the camera to ignore OBS and do the right thing), or if you'd be fine with switching to some other video recording app that doesn't have the bug OBS seems to have.

Comment: Oh yes I would definitely be open to using different software.